# How to frequency shift an audio file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft, resampling

I am reading two audio files (mp3/wav) which are bandlimited to 15kHz.

```
[audio1 fs]=audioread('test1.mp3');
[audio2 fs]=audioread('test2.mp3');
```

I want to combine audio1 and audio2 into a single audio file in such a way that the first audio file (audio1) is band limited between 1-15kHz and the second (audio2) is band limited between 16-30kHz.

Comment: So, do you want to crop the audio, or modulate it in higher frequencies? Just in case, note that a human can not hear more than 16KHz on average

Comment: I know humans cannot hear above 20kHz. My application involves modulating the audio to higher frequency (16-30kHz) and combine them to get a new file with 0-30kHz.

Comment: You can use the same technique that is used for generating [SSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-sideband_modulation) in RF applications - use a 15 kHz "carrier" frequency modulated by audio2 and generate the upper side band only - then add this to the other baseband signal (audio1).